# How can I prevent naked URLs from turning into links?

Tags: support, feature-request, markdown

I've read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help, but did not find anything on how to prevent naked URLs from turning into links. In the previous sentence, it makes sense that the naked URL is turned into a link.

When I try access foo, I always get the error message

> ERROR 404: You cannot access http://localhost/foo at the moment.

In the previous sentence, it's a distraction that *http://localhost/foo* (here we go again) is turned into a link. How can I prevent that?

If it is not possible to prevent naked URLs from being turned into links, I propose to make it possible to prevent naked URLs from being turned into links.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible — simply wrap the URL in an inline code span: `http://localhost/foo`

Comment: Good point. I did not think about this, because I find it semantically unsatisfying.

Comment: For some reason, I'm personally fine with it. And I'm usually vocally against misuse of code spans.

Comment: @Oswald if it's in an error traceback, per your example, then shouldn't that all be in a code block anyway?